# Cannot find module 'karma' while using grunt

Tags: angularjs, npm, gruntjs, yeoman, bower

I am using [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io) toolkit to bootstrap an [Angular](http://angularjs.org) web application. I've followed all the steps mentioned [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/kickstart-your-angularjs-development-with-yeoman-grunt-and-bower/). But still, apparently, `grunt` can not find the `karma` module. It spits out this error:

```
Loading "grunt-karma.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'karma'
Warning: Task "karma" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

I've tried installing `karma` both locally and globally using `npm`, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Make sure you have installed both karma and grunt-karma before running the grunt task:

```
npm install karma
npm install grunt-karma
```

**EDIT: One liner:**

```
npm install karma grunt-karma
```

Comment: I have the same problem, but this did not fix it for me.

Comment: I just added this information. It's now in the ["Getting Started" guide](https://github.com/karma-runner/grunt-karma#getting-started)

Answer (score 10):

I had to install the following

```
  npm install phantomjs
  npm install jasmine-core
  npm install karma
  npm install grunt-karma
```

Goodluck, Rajesh

**Edit: One liner:**

```
npm install karma grunt-karma jasmine-core phantomjs
```

Answer (score 5):

This work for me:

```
npm install phantomjs jasmine-core jasmine karma grunt-karma
```

Node version: `4.2.2`

Comment: In addition to what @d.danailov suggested, I also had to run:  
`npm install karma-jasmine karma-firefox-launcher karma-phantomjs-launcher karma-junit-reporter   karma-html-reporter karma-coverage --save-dev`

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and running `npm install karma` fixed it temporarily too.

The issue though wasn't that karma hadn't been initialized but rather that the repository that we were using had `node_modules` checked in without karma's debug folder.

This was all because the `.gitignore` file was ignoring all the debug folders for checkins. Make sure your `.gitignore` file isn't ignoring things you want

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install karma
npm install grunt-karma
```

above command will fix the issue.